# How to find repetitions and cycles in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have such data:

```
,33788753,2017-01-18,,
,23504360,2017-01-18,,
,33806822,2017-01-19,,
,23516368,2017-01-19,,
,33825653,2017-01-20,,
,23521292,2017-01-20,,
```

I would like to spot if for every date there are exactly n values (in this case two)

Other little different case is to check whether the cycle is maintained for the date and another column (category); like so:

```
,33788753,2017-01-18,A,
,23504360,2017-01-19,B,
,33806822,2017-01-20,C,
,23516368,2017-01-18,A,
,33825653,2017-01-19,B,
,23521292,2017-01-20,C,
```

I came across different possibilities Excel conditional formatting options, I didn't find any for the two options.
I can achieve results with programming languages like Python using pandas grouping and counting functions. But I prefer Excel for speed and colors.

Knowing that I'm guessing (not sure) the two problems can be done via conditional formatting.

Comment: Your sample data has already been sorted by date.  Is your full dataset already sorted by date??

Comment: yes, it is. but I'm not sure of counts! and cycles if they are maintained (cycle of n days with n ordered categories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the rule type `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`, and enter the following formula for the first problem (the one with two columns):

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B,$B1)=2
```

Here's the formula for the second problem:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)=2
```

**Result:**

I've modified your sample data to show the difference.

[image: Problem 1]

[image: Problem 2]